# Distributed SSE with Spring SseEmitter

Tags: java, spring-boot, server-sent-events

If multiple instances of a service are running they have to fetch `SseEmitter` objects from a shared storage.

Is it possible to store `SseEmitter` objects on a shared storage? If yes, please help me with the approach.

Thank you!